# Get past request without waiting for response (Angular 2 +)

Tags: json, angular, asynchronous, get

I am looking for data in an API via Get request, I need the data inside my OnInit to use in composing other data. The problem is that the method is being called but it is as an async method (without await), it passes everywhere but when the return is obtained the excution of the main method has already been finished with no results. I tried the implementation of asynchronous methods but it did not solve.

**service:**

```
getObjects(): MyClass[] {
let objects = new Array<MyClass>();

this.obterTodos<MyClass>(this.uriApi)
    .map(res => res.map(x => new MyClass(x.Description, x.Id)))
    .subscribe(entities => {
         objects = entities;
    });

    return objects ;
}
```

**get request**

```
public getObjects<TEntity>(url: string): Observable<TEntity[]> {
    return this.httpService
      .get(this.serviceUrl + url, this.options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myObjects= this.setorService.obterSetores();
    console.log('this.myObjects is empty here');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you'll want to subscribe to your observable in the component. This is typically done so the component can determine when the http request should be ran & so the component can wait for the http request to finish (and follow with some logic).

```
// subscribe to observable somewhere in your component (like ngOnInit)
this.setorService.obterSetores().subscribe(
    res => {
        this.myObjects = res;
    },
    err => {}
)
```

now the component knows when the http request finishes

Comment: The problem with this is that I will have to replicate the code on every component I want to get that list of objects from an api ... is that right?

Comment: that is correct. one thing you can do is to store the results of the api when it is initially called. then every subsequent component that needs data can used the stored data